How to get rid of the glitches in exported animation from blender
I have created an animation without any glitches, and it does not show any when I render the frames for animation in Blender. After that, I imported those frames in the video editing tab in Blender to export them as a video MPEG-4. It doesn't show any glitches in the result if I play it, but it shows glitches when I import it into Premier Pro or play it on my phone, I also tried changing the output quality to high, mid, low, etc in video setting. Can anyone help me get rid of these glitches?



